# How i make Slider Class get only 60%vh not 100%

Tags: javascript

How i make Slider Class get only 60%vh not 100%

```
$(function(){
  'use strict';
  var winH = $(window).height(),
    topB = $('#top-header').innerHeight(),
    navH = $('.navbar').innerHeight();
    $('.slider').height(winH - ( topB + navH));
});
```

Comment: `$('.slider').height((winH - ( topB + navH)) * 0.6);`

Comment: thanks a lot it's work as well